# Oracle database not open and ORA-00600 error

Tags: oracle, startup

Whenever I try to open Oracle, I get following error : 
    ORA-01109: database not open

So as suggested by various blog and forum, I tried the following series of commands

```
c:> sqlplus /nolog
sql> connect sys/manager as sysdba
sql> shutdown immediate
sql> startup
```

(and startup mount, startup force etc)

I get 
    ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS options for database open

If I try :

```
SQL> alter database open noresetlogs;

I get error ORA-00600: internal error code error
```

And if I try resetlogs after recovery, I get the following option :

```
ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup
```

I do not have any important data on the database, I was just starting up for a dummy project. So I don't care much about data, my target is to just work with ORACLE with some new tables.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Or maybe even better - contact Oracle support. There might be various solutions like disable parallel recovery, completely bypass media recovery or apply some ad-hoc patch before opening the database, but it's better when it is recommended by Oracle support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database experienced an incomplete recovery. This is why it complains about open resetlogs. After an incomplete recovery you need resetlogs. To be able to get this database up and running again, you need to know what caused the current situation and some skills to get it out of there.

If the data is not important at all, just trash the database and create a new one. The actions needed for this depend a little on the platform where you are on.

[the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm) looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Check the volumes on the server. It is likely that you have filled the FRA and it can't grow any more which is preventing RMAN from performing the required tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you encounter the ORA-00600 :[2662] internal error:

```
The ORA-600 [2662] is raised when data block SCN is ahead of the current SCN.
This is generally related to the redo application which is used to bring the database to a consistent state.
```

You'd better restore whole database  from rman backup ,it may fix this problem. If any backup is unavailable , then PRM-DUL (an Oracle Recovery/Rescue Tools ) can be your last resort .